# on checkout page, no shipping address field appearing

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1.3, address

I only see the field to put email address, payment options.
I tried switching to other themes (Luma and Blank), but the checkout page was the same.

Are some settings missing?

[image]

Comment: Any chance to attach a screenshot?

Comment: I have added the screenshot

Comment: Your account is logged or not? Seem that you're using third party extension?

Comment: not logged, and doesn't matter if I activate third party extension (in this case I have IWD one page checkout installed) or not, the screen is the same.

Comment: Do you add to card Virtual/Downloadable product? Because if you have no shipping address step and don't use 3rd party extension it seems like you are using some product.

Comment: Dear Max, that was the reason! I have configurable products and created associated products without giving weight, so as virtual. Once I made it to simple product, the shipping address field appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because my configurable product has associated products as virtual, not simple.

I didn't add weight as I do not offer shipping fee based on the weight of the product. So I thought not necessary. But sure, if the item is virtual, doesn't need to be delivered physically, so there is no shipping address field.

Thank you [Max](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/34350/max-pronko)!